# Does anybody Encountered this Error when uninstalling XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, webserver

[Prompt during uninstallation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WItaA.png)
I was trying to uninstall my xampp for some reason but I always get this error when performing the operation.

I already tried using control panel & windows settings->app to uninstall the xampp but still this prompt kept on showing upon operation.

Thank you.